# Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

So we are using the forge viewer API, but when we upload file it doesn't show on the viewer and we end up with a gray viewer.

The file transcription to svf seems to not be working properly.

Anyone experience or know how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with different files ? Can you check the manifest ? Is there any error ?

Comment: Hi Alex, we do have the issue with other files cause none of them work and the issue we get is unable to translate file into SVF, sadly.

Comment: Ok. So it's hard to investigate more your problem without any code. Can you try to use one of the Autodesk Forge samples ? You will see if the problem is related to your code or your files.

Comment: I tried investigating to see if it's code or file related. I used the Autodesk viewer as an example and the same files work perfectly. When we load the file and prepare for the viewer is the issue, we use the viewer code provided on the forge Documentation.

Comment: This is the viewer and all we see, https://www.dropbox.com/t/qUqdsselQ6EdouU3

Comment: Can you check the inspector ? Any viewer error ?

Comment: I did check the viewer and it seems to be running fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check if your file is well uploaded in your bucket (I assume that your using Buckets/Object with 2-legged OAuth).

Using this endpoint your must see your uploaded files : [Get Objects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/)

In the response, you will find the `objectId`. This `objectId` need to be converted into base64 and URL Safe for the `SVF` translation.

Now, following this tutorial, you will be able to translate your file : [Translate to SVF](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/option1/)

Please note the response of this request to get the most information about this job.

Finally, check the manifest to know when the translation is complete.

Comment: Noted, followed the steps and explanation which are helpful for some weird reason still facing some errors, would you mind a screen share call ?

Comment: Can you share parts of your manifest or the response of the translate request ? You're facing some errors, but can you share its (error message, http status code ...) ? Without any error message or sample of your code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: "The file transcription to svf seems to not be working properly." Yes, that seems to be the case. When I upload the file you provided to your sample app, there is no manifest generated for the file - i.e. it looks like you did not submit a translation job. Could you please provide the code that you use to kick off the translation?